# Deallocate contiguous block of memory for a 2D array

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, free

I understand I'm splitting the array over the double pointer, but how can I deallocate if I lost the data track?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define width 20
#define height 20

void allocate_matrix(int ***matrix)
{
    double **local_matrix, *data;
    local_matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * height);
    data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * width * height);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        local_matrix[i] = &(data[i * width]);
    }
    *matrix = local_matrix;
}

void deallocate_matrix(int **matrix) {
    
}

int main(void) {
    int **matrix;
    allocate_matrix(&matrix);
    deallocate_matrix(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `void allocate_matrix(int ***matrix):  [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't lose track of the second pointer.  If you look at your loop body:

```
local_matrix[i] = &(data[i * width]);
```

When `i` is 0, `local_matrix[0]` is assigned `&data[0]` which is the same as `data`.  So that's what you need to free:

```
void deallocate_matrix(int **matrix) {
    free(matrix[0]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are allocating space for `double` then use it as `int`, which doesn't make sense (and will not compile).

But the main problem here is that you shouldn't be allocating this as fragmented segments but as a contiguous 2D array. Please study [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). This will give a major performance boost and may (arguably) make the code a bit easier to read as well.

If we follow the advise in that post, then your code could be rewritten as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocate_matrix(size_t height, size_t width, int (**matrix)[height][width])
{
    int (*local_matrix) [height][width];
    local_matrix = malloc(sizeof *local_matrix);
    if(local_matrix == NULL)
    {
      // handle errors
    }
    *matrix = local_matrix;
}

int main (void) 
{
    const size_t height = 20;
    const size_t width  = 20;
    int (*matrix)[height][width];
    allocate_matrix(height, width, &matrix);

    int(*pmatrix)[width] = *matrix; // pointer to first 1D array for easier syntax
    for(size_t h=0; h<height; h++)
    {
      for(size_t w=0; w<width; w++)
      {
        pmatrix[h][w] = h+w; // assign some sort of data
        printf("%d ", pmatrix[h][w]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see this also eliminated the need for a complex deallocation routine, since we can just pass the pointer directly to `free()` and deallocate everything at one single place.

Comment: Sorry, the int parameter its a typo

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. needs the header file: `stdlib.h` for the prototypes for exit() and malloc() and EXIT_FAILURE
2. performs the desired functionality
3. you might want to modify the calculation of the initialization values of the matrix

and now, the proposed code:

```
double **allocate_matrix(void)
{
    local_matrix** = malloc( sizeof(double *) * height );
    if( ! local_matrix )
    {
        perror( "malloc for matrix height failed:");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    for( size_t y = 0; y<height; y++ )
    {
        local_matrix[y] = malloc( sizeof(double) * width );
        if( !local_matrix[y] )
        {
            //cleanup and exit
        }
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            local_matrix[y][i] = i;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    return local_matrix;
} 


int main( void )
{
    double **matrix;

    matrix = allocate_matrix();
    
    for( size_t y= 0; y< height; y++ )
    {
        free( matrix[ y ] ):
    }
    free( matrix );
}
```